# Define a function that reads a position from a file and returns an object representing that particular position

Tags: python, oop

I don't know how to create a function that takes as an argument  the name of a text file, reads a position from that file and returns an object representing the position where the file must contain one line for each row of the board, using the characters `"."`, `"@"`, and `"O"` as above to represent the colours.

`def load_board(filename):`

and also to create a function `save_board(filename, board)` that takes as arguments a filename and a `Board` object and saves the position to a text file in the same format as that accepted by `load_board()`.

so that

```
b = load_board("l19.txt")
print(b)
save_board("l19b.txt", b)
```

reads a file consisting of:

```
v     ....@@@.OO..@.OOO.O
@OO@O@..@O@O...@@.@
@O..@O.OOOOO.OOOOO@
..@@.OO.@..O@O.@.O.
O.@.@.O@.OO@@O..O@O
O...OOO@.@@...@.O@@
..@O@..@..OOO.@.@..
..@@.@@@...@O.O...@
@O..@.@@@@O..@OOO@O
@..O.@@O@OO@@.@.O@.
@OOO..@O..@@O@@@.OO
@@O@.OOO.@.O@.@@@.@
@.O.O@OO.OO.@O@..@O
@...O@@OO@.@@..O.O.
OO@@..O@@.@.@.O@@O.
@.O..OO.@O@O@OO.@@.
@@OO@.O.@.O@.@O@O..
...OO@@O.@O.O.@OO@.
@@.@O.@@..@OOOOO@@@
```

which gives an output of

```
   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S
19 . . . . @ @ @ . O O . . @ . O O O . O
18 @ O O @ O @ . . @ O @ O . . . @ @ . @
17 @ O . . @ O . O O O O O . O O O O O @
16 . . @ @ . O O . @ . . O @ O . @ . O .
15 O . @ . @ . O @ . O O @ @ O . . O @ O
14 O . . . O O O @ . @ @ . . . @ . O @ @
13 . . @ O @ . . @ . . O O O . @ . @ . .
12 . . @ @ . @ @ @ . . . @ O . O . . . @
11 @ O . . @ . @ @ @ @ O . . @ O O O @ O
10 @ . . O . @ @ O @ O O @ @ . @ . O @ .
 9 @ O O O . . @ O . . @ @ O @ @ @ . O O
 8 @ @ O @ . O O O . @ . O @ . @ @ @ . @
 7 @ . O . O @ O O . O O . @ O @ . . @ O
 6 @ . . . O @ @ O O @ . @ @ . . O . O .
 5 O O @ @ . . O @ @ . @ . @ . O @ @ O .
 4 @ . O . . O O . @ O @ O @ O O . @ @ .
 3 @ @ O O @ . O . @ . O @ . @ O @ O . .
 2 . . . O O @ @ O . @ O . O . @ O O @ .
 1 @ @ . @ O . @ @ . . @ O O O O O @ @ @
```

and save_board should create a file identical to this grid which was the file that was used to get the above output

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this as some sort of game board, you want a separate function for printing the board

```
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        board = [list(line.strip()) for line in lines]
        return board


def save_board(filename, board):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join([''.join(line) + '\n' for line in board]))


def print_board(board):
    result = f"    {' '.join([chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(len(board[0]))])}\n"

    for y, row in enumerate(board):
        result += f"{str(abs(y-len(board))):>3s} {' '.join(row)}\n"

    print(result)


b = load_board("file.txt")
print_board(b)
print(f"{b[0][-1] = }") # '0'
save_board('file.txt', b)
```

Whenever you want to print the board using that format, use the print_board function.
Now whenever you want to access a character at a certain position in the board you can use b[y][x]
For example to find the character at position (2, 3) you would do b[3][2] which would be '@'

Note: indexes start at 0 in python

Comment: Thank you soo much. I'm getting an error --> NameError: name 'board' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Board'?

Comment: it does not print the grid and I'm not sure why

Comment: and i used board_file.readlines() to return a list containing each line from the file cause that's more convenient

Comment: by the way this is created outside the class

Comment: I've edited the question a bit

Comment: I just updated my answer to better answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try yourself first;

```
def load_board(filename):
    result = "  "
    with open(filename) as f:
        print(f)
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == 0:
                result += ' '.join([chr(alphabets + 65) for alphabets in range(len(line) - 1)]) + '\n'
            result += f"{index+1}"
            for characters in line:
                result += " " + characters
            result += "\n"
        
        return result

def save_board(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "wt") as f:
        f.write(data)

b = load_board("l19.txt")
print(b)
save_board("l19b.txt", b)
```